# If statement condition is met, but contents not executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an two `if()` statements, for which the conditions are both met with the default values in the `<select>` and `<input>` form fields I've tested this by assigning the values to a variable and writing the variable. (`0` and `Url`).

However, it seems that neither `if()` statement's contents execute properly.

**Here's a link to my JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cfRAk/2/

Any edits/answers as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please define "neither...execute properly" by telling us what you expect to happen, and what unexpected thing is now happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code you're asking about:

```
$('#post-form').click( function() {  
    var geo_select_val = $('select[name=g_country\\[1\\]]').val();          
    if(!geo_select_val) {
        var geo_url_val = $('input[name=g_url\\[1\\]]').val();
        if(geo_url_val != "http://google.com") {
            $('#notification').html("You need to enter a valid url");
        }
    }
});
```

When I set a breakpoint in this click function and then click on the Post Form div, `geo_select_val` comes back as `"0"` which means that `if(!geo_select_val)` will fail because `geo_select_val` does have a value so the first if condition will never be executed.

Perhaps you want the first if condition to be:

```
if (geo_select_val != "0") {
```

which will tell you if some other value besides the default has been selected (assuming you add other options to that select tag with different values).

Comment: Ah apologies. The transition from PHP to JS is harder than I thought, as 0 is considered false in PHP. Thanks for your answer, I'll accept when the timer drops.

Comment: `0` the number is considered `false` in javascript too.  But a string `"0"` is not a `false` value.  jQuery's `.val()` returns a string, not a number which will only be false if it is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
var geo_select_val = $('select[name=g_country\\[1\\]]').val();
```

To this:

```
var geo_select_val = parseInt($('select[name=g_country\\[1\\]]').val());
```

The thing is `geo_select_val` is actually `"0"` and not `0`. Converting a string to boolean will only result in `false` if string is empty. `"0"` is not empty, so it was being evaluated as true. Since you are going `!geo_select_val`, it never goes in.

Caveat: this fix will only work if you make sure all values are numbers. If that's not the case, check for equality with `"0"`